# Can we add a close button to the hat popup?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winterbash

I'm having a lot of fun with the Hat Dash (I swear, Gaming.SE gets the best toys), but there's a minor UI issue that's bugging me.  When you click a hat on the Hat Dash home page or another user's profile, you get a hat popup with no obvious way to close it:

[image: hat!][1]

Now, clicking outside a popup is on the short list of things to try when you don't know how to close it, but it would be nice to avoid the "don't know how to close it" issue in the first place.  A gold "X" at the right-hand edge of the upper ribbon would be a welcome addition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. we can.
There is a need for some other additional buttons too.